# Function approximating this product

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Is there any function approximating, for large values of $p$, the quotient between the product of all primes and the product of all primes $-1$?

Basically: $2/1 \cdot 3/2 \cdot 5/4 \cdot 7/6 \cdot 11/10 \cdots $

Can that be approximated, for large values of $p$, with some known function?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

To find the behavior of

$$
\prod_{p \leq x} \frac{p}{p-1} = \prod_{p \leq x} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}
$$

We begin by taking its logarithm, which we then rewrite as

$$
\log \prod_{p \leq x} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1} = - \sum_{p \leq x} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).
$$

Now $\log(1-1/p) \sim -1/p$ for large $p$, so this should yield a good first approximation.  After pulling this out we obtain a sum which converges, so let's rewrite the quantity as

$$
\begin{align}
&- \sum_{p \leq x} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \\
&\qquad = \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} - \sum_{p \leq x} \left[\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) + \frac{1}{p}\right] \\
&\qquad = \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} - \sum_{p} \left[\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) + \frac{1}{p}\right] + \sum_{p > x} \left[\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) + \frac{1}{p}\right]. \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
$$

According to Mertens' formula (see the second entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Mertens.27_second_theorem_and_the_prime_number_theorem), where $M$ is the [Meissel-Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant)),

$$
\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} - \sum_{p} \left[\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) + \frac{1}{p}\right] = \log\log x + \gamma + o\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right).
$$

Using Mertens' formula again with the [Abel summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) it's possible to show that the final sum in $(*)$ is also $o\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)$, allowing us to conclude that

$$
-\sum_{p \leq x} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) = \log\log x + \gamma + o\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right).
$$

Exponentiating this we find that

> $$
> \prod_{p \leq x} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1} = e^\gamma \log x + o(1).
> $$

If you'd like, you can replace $x$ by $p_n$, the $n^\text{th}$ prime, and use [the estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)

$$
p_n \approx n\log n + n\log\log n - n + \cdots
$$

to see that the product of the first $n$ primes is

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)^{-1} &= e^\gamma \log p_n + o(1) \\
> &\approx e^\gamma \log\Bigl(n \log n + n\log\log n - n\Bigr).
> \end{align}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for an approximation of  $$\prod_{p\leq n} \frac{p}{p-1}$$
It is well known that  $\prod_{p\leq n} \frac{p}{p-1} \simeq lnn$.
For more details and to learn how Euler used this fact to prove something really interesting see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Proofs)