# asymptotic of a product

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

So the question that I'm working on is the following.

Show that $\Pi_{p\leq z}(1-\dfrac{1}{p})=\dfrac{C(1+\mathcal{o}(1))}{\log z}$.

First off I take logs and just work with the sum and thisis what I get.
$$\sum_{p\leq z}\log (1-\dfrac{1}{p})=-\sum_{p\leq z}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{np^{n}} $$

now so now I want to show that this sum is $-\log\log z +C' +\mathcal{o}(\log x^{-1})$.

But I'm not sure on who to do this, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I show what you seek in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/643947/5531) by appealing to a strengthened version of Mertens' formula, but I'm not sure if that's the road you'd like to take.

Comment: Actually, since you only want to show that $\prod_{p \leq z} (1-1/p) \sim C/\log z$ then you don't need the strengthened formula with the little o.  Using the elementary version of Mertens' formula with error $O(1/\log z)$ will still yield the desired answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\Lambda(d)$$
$$\ln(\lfloor x \rfloor!)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\rfloor$$
$$x\ln(x)+O(x)=x\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}+O(x)$$
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}=\ln(x)+O(1)$$
$$\text{ Now conclude your result using summation by parts}$$

Comment: And use summation by parts on what sum?  also I don't see how you can get the little oh out of this?

Comment: Yea my bad, you wont be able to get the little O term out of this, I thought you were asking for something weaker. You could look at Tao's http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/mertens-theorems/, if your comfortable with his Fourier analytic stuff.